# I can't filter the column description in the datacatalog(GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, qualifiers, google-data-catalog

I'm trying to filter the gcp data catalog, in which I try to filter column descriptions, using the description qualifiers: student name attribute.
Unfortunately, no return.

other qualifiers that I couldn't get back were also:

- type=tag_template
- system=data_catalog

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

May I ask what is the column description and what is the exact query you are searching for?
Column descriptions should be searchable.

If you are using the data catalog UI, on the main search page tag templates (and entry groups) are hidden as they show on separate pages.
[image: Screenshot where to find stuff entry groups and tag templates]